# Как создать подобие id vk?

Tags: php, .htaccess

страница пользователя вк располагается по адресу vk.com/id1 , но в голове только такая структура site.ru/user?m=id1... как можно повторить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^site.ru/user/(.*)?$ /site.ru/user?m=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Под рукой нет appache. Но вроде без ошибок.

Comment: а если будет функция добавлять собственный название, но оно допустим будет начинаться с @  принцип тот же?

Comment: Да. Принцип такой же. Или можно через какой-нибудь router.php который будет парсить url и отображать соответствующую страницу.

Comment: хм, второй вариант мне нравится больше, надо подумать